# NodeJS promises vs. callbacks: is there a reason not to support both?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I was wondering today whether I could not simply support both callbacks and promises. Are there any downsides you can think of?

```
function fetchUser(data, success, error) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var body = {
        sharedSecret: config['apiSharedSecret'],
        deviceAuth: data.deviceAuth,
        username: data.username,
        phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber
    };

    request.post({
        url: url,
        json: body,
    }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(err));
            if (typeof error === "function") {
               error.call(this, err);
            }  
            return;
        }            

        if (typeof success === "function") {
            success.call(this, body);
        }

        deferred.resolve(body);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Just educate your user to embrace promises :-) There's no need for callback parameters any more.

Comment: Please remember that promises are callbacks too, but they have lots more features and capabilities than plain callbacks, particularly when it comes to async error propagation and managing multiple async operations.  So, your question is really more like why should you support the form of callbacks that has so many less features when the one with lots more features is now considered a standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside is that it can make your code more complex. Also there is no situation where callbacks have any advantage over promises so there is no point in doing this. But if you want to do it you should probably write a function like this to avoid code duplication.

```
function defer(success, error) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  deferred.promise.then(success, error);
  return deferred;
}
```

Comment: Promises makes the code cleaner (and recently I've discovered generators which seems to take code elegancy a step forward), however aren't there any situations where it is easier to debug callbacks?

Comment: I can't think of any such situation. Do you have an example?